# Pass form values in querystring to another page using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass the values from form inputs to another page using vanilla javascript. I'm using URLSearchParams and querystrings to get the values and can successfully display them on the same page. What I cannot figure out is how to send the form values to another page and display them on that page. I have created a pen with the form here: https://codepen.io/JapperCat/pen/ExRKJyV

```
<form action="./page2.html" id="sample-form">
  <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fullname">

  <br><br>

  <label for="age">Age</label>
  <input type="text" name="age">

  <br><br>

  <label for="gender">Gender</label>
  <select name="gender" id="gender">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

  <br><br>

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">

  <br><br>

  <label for="mytoys">My Toys</label>

  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="mytoys" name="mytoys" value="Bike">
  <label for="bike"> I have a bike</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="mytoys" name="mytoys" value="Car">
  <label for="car"> I have a car</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="mytoys" name="mytoys" value="Boat">
  <label for="boat"> I have a boat</label><br><br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p id="showFullname"></p>
<p id="showAge"></p>
<p id="showGender"></p>
<p id="showEmail"></p>
<p id="favToy"></p>

<script>
  const form = document.getElementById("sample-form");
  form.addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const params = new URLSearchParams(formData);
    // Convert to raw query string
    console.log(params.toString());
    // Loop over each key-value pairs using array destructuring
    for (const [key, value] of params) {
      console.log(`${key} => ${value}`);

      // Output result of inputs
      const fullname = params.get("fullname");
      const age = params.get("age");
      const gender = params.get("gender");
      const email = params.get("email");
      const mytoys = params.get("mytoys");
      // Display values on screen
      document.getElementById("showFullname").innerHTML = `Your full name is: ${fullname}`;
      document.getElementById("showAge").innerHTML = `Your age is: ${age}`;
      document.getElementById("showGender").innerHTML = `Your gender is: ${gender}`;
      document.getElementById("showEmail").innerHTML = `Your email is: ${email}`;
      document.getElementById("favToy").innerHTML = `Your favorite toy is: ${mytoys}`;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The rules of this coding challenge restrict me from using frameworks or libraries, (no jQuery) and no cookies, local or session storage.

Comment: What actual issue are you having?

Comment: I know how to display the form results on the same page. What I cannot figure out is how to send or pass the form results to a second page and then display the form results on the second page instead of the first page.

Comment: You can pass it as a query string from the URL, but you are required to use window.location for the purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass the values in a query string from the URL using window.location method. I am a noob at javascript and trying to learn it using vanilla javascript.

Comment: I've posted an answer to send a GET request with the data, or were you trying to use POST?

Comment: @ArleighHix : Your solution almost works for me except it only sends the query string to page2.html. I need the values to be displayed on page 2 inside a div#results.

Comment: So you need to access the GET parameters in page 2 and display them.

Comment: @ArleighHix : I have created another pen for page2.html https://codepen.io/JapperCat/pen/qBKNBME and have added the script there but it still isn't getting the results from the form and populating the fields. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added to my answer, it should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your checkboxes are invalid because they all have the same `id` every element needs to have a unique `id`. Also, since they appear to belong in an array together (same `name`) the `name` should have brackets `[]` after it i.e `name="mytoys[]"`.
After building your query string, all you have to do is concatenate it with the URL of the page you whish to send it to (I'm assuming you want to send it to the URL in the `form.action`)

```js
const GetURL = `${form.action}?${params.toString()}`;
```

Then to send a GET Request use `window.location(GetURL)`.

In my snippet I've added a `confirm()` popup to show the URL before sending the Request. It will look something like this: `https://stacksnippets.net/page2.html?fullname=dude&age=9&gender=Male&email=dude%40mail.com&mytoys%5B%5D=Bike&mytoys%5B%5D=Boat` The `stacksnippets.net/` part is there because the `action` is a relative URL, and will have the domain of wherever it is running.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("sample-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(formData);
  // Convert to raw query string
  const GetURL = `${form.action}?${params.toString()}`;
  console.log(GetURL);
  if (confirm(`Submitting GET Request to: ${GetURL}`)) {
    // confirm is for demo, you only need this next line
    window.location = GetURL;
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="./page2.html" id="sample-form">
  <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fullname">
  <br><br>
  <label for="age">Age</label>
  <input type="text" name="age">
  <br><br>
  <label for="gender">Gender</label>
  <select name="gender" id="gender">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  <br><br>
  <label for="mytoys[]">My Toys</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mytoys_bike" name="mytoys[]" value="Bike">
  <label for="bike"> I have a bike</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="mytoys_car" name="mytoys[]" value="Car">
  <label for="car"> I have a car</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="mytoys_boat" name="mytoys[]" value="Boat">
  <label for="boat"> I have a boat</label><br><br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Your `page2.html` will look something like the following snippet.
Note, I had to use some dummy data to replicate the value of `window.location.search` as this will not work in the snippet.

```js
const dummy = 'fullname=dude&age=9&gender=Male&email=dude%40mail.com&mytoys%5B%5D=Bike&mytoys%5B%5D=Boat'
const fields = ['fullname', 'age', 'gender', 'email', 'mytoys[]']
const results = document.querySelector('#results');
const queryString = window.location.search;
// won't work in fiddle/snippet
//const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
// using dummy string here
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(dummy);

fields.forEach((param) => {
  console.log(urlParams.getAll(param))
  const dispVal = urlParams.getAll(param).join(', ')
  results.append(`${param}: ${dispVal}`)
  results.append(document.createElement('br'))
})
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

[page2 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tufgzmd/2/)